# How to use where clasue and call a method using generic parameter in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `ContainerElementCtrl` class and `MainContainer` in which I am trying to call methods in `ContainerElementCtrl` class from my `MainContainer` class using the generic parameter that get to `setDataInUI` methods in `MainContainer` class.

To achieve that I am trying to restrict the generic parametr `T` types using
`where T : DataA, DataB` where clause which gives me an error.

How can I achieve this?

`ContainerElementCtrl .cs`

```
public class ContainerElementCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void setData(DataA tabTypeAData)
    {
        Debug.Log("setData type A " + tabTypeAData.title);
    }

    public void setData(DataB tabTypeBData)
    {
        Debug.Log("setData type B " + tabTypeBData.title);
    }
}
```

`MainContainer.cs`

```
public class MainContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject containerElement;


    public void setDataInUI<T>(T m_tabsData) 
        where T : DataA, DataB
    {
        containerElement.setData(m_tabsData);
    }
}


public class DataA
{
    public string title;
    public string picUrl;
}

public class DataB
{
    public string title;
}
```

Comment: Create overloads for `where T : DataA` and `where T : DataB`. But why do you have two `setData()` methods in the first place? Can't you generalize that code so it eats one shared interface that both `DataA` and `DataB` implement? Or rather, let `DataA` and `DataB` implement their own rendering logic? A container shouldn't have to know how to render its children; children should be able to render themselves.

Comment: Do `DataA` and `DataB` share a common base class or interface?

Comment: updated question with DataA, DataB classes

Comment: Both `setData` implement different logic , which can't be generialized

Comment: It sounds like basically this isn't a good fit for generics, so be honest. A generic method that can only be called with one of two types sounds like it should probably be two separate methods, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can only provide multiple interfaces for the type constraints and a single class. So create a common interface for your data classes and use that as the constraint. You also should use a single generic method in the `ContainerElementCtrl`

```cs
public class ContainerElementCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SetData<T>(T tabData) where T : IData
    {
        Console.WriteLine("setData type " + typeof(T) + " " + tabData.Title);
    }
}

public interface IData
{
    string Title { get; set; }
}
public class DataA : IData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PicUrl;
}

public class DataB : IData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class MainContainer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ContainerElementCtrl containerElement;

    public void setDataInUI<T>(T tabsData) where T : IData
    {
        containerElement.SetData(tabsData);
    }
}
```